# Deploy .net 4.0 binaries in the same folder as the application folder

Tags: .net, deployment, setup-deployment

I have to deploy an application that targets .net 4.0 framework.

I use a zip that packages all binaries and deliver (unzip) them on the "client" to a specified folder. For security reasons I have to use only the specified folder.

Given that the "client" doesn't have .net 4.0 installed, is it possible to include .net 4.0 binaries in that zip. What binaries should I include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a full installer you might be able to bootstrap the .NET runtime installation, but you can't simply xcopy-deploy .NET; for "normal" usage, your user is going to need the .NET runtime installed. This is a system level package that installs into pre-determined locations that you don't get to choose.

There *are* specialized tools that try to work around this, such as thinstall or [Salamander](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/), but they aren't usually free. Additional, this is not "normal", and all usual support / reliability expectations would be off the table.